# execute command on ec2 after ssh login using bash script

Tags: bash, ssh, amazon-ec2, xterm

This code opens up three windows on my system and logs in into three different ec2 instances.

```
(xterm -geometry 70x70-0-0 -e ssh -i key1 ec2-user@52.x.x.x;) & 
(xterm -geometry 70x70+485-200 -e ssh -i key1 ec2-user@52.x.x.x;) &
(xterm -geometry 70x70+0-0 -e ssh -i key1 ec2-user@52.x.x.x;)
```

However, I want to login into these three instances and execute respective commands in them. Something like:

```
(xterm -geometry 70x70-0-0 -e ssh -i key1 ec2-user@52.x.x.x; **run python file on this instance**) & 
(xterm -geometry 70x70+485-200 -e ssh -i key1 ec2-user@52.x.x.x; **run node file on this instance**) &
(xterm -geometry 70x70+0-0 -e ssh -i key1 ec2-user@52.x.x.x; **run R file on this instance**)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing to change is getting rid of the semicolon before the "** run" (as well as using a real command).  Something like

`(xterm -geometry 70x70-0-0 -e ssh -i key1 ec2-user@52.x.x.x`  *`**`run python file on this instance`**`* `) &` 
   `(xterm -geometry 70x70+485-200 -e ssh -i key1 ec2-user@52.x.x.x`  *`**`run node file on this instance`**`* `) &`
   `(xterm -geometry 70x70+0-0 -e ssh -i key1 ec2-user@52.x.x.x`  *`**run R file on this instance***` `) &`

After the options (such as `-i`) and login information, `ssh` accepts a command and arguments.

Comment: all 3 windows disappear after executing. None of them stays. I tried using -hold but I cannot continue executing other commands after the window holds

Comment: Your question should clarify how you expect to run the scripts.  It did not mention the possibility of them quitting early.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
(xterm -geometry 70x70-0-0 -e ssh -i key1 ec2-user@52.x.x.x -t "script.py ; bash";) &
```

the `-t` option make a tty and with `bash` after `script.py` you would get an interactive bash to continue commanding.